# In DBeaver, how to open multiple database connections in different tabs

Tags: mysql, database, dbeaver

I have two database connections. By default, they are appearing one below another. But I want them to show side by side (like browser tabs). I have searched for this and unable to found such setting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in DBeaver. This would likely be a feature in Preferences->User Interface->Navigator. It seems that the hierarchical folder view is the entirety of the interface.

Comment: There is the concept of "Projects" where you could have one database connection in one project and the other in another project. The projects won't be switchable through a tab interface, but it does keep the navigation and script save locations and other stuff separate.